# Класс не может быть найден. Контроллер с измененным namespace

Tags: php, yii2

Спрашиваю в связи с тем, что на локалке с опенсервера вопросов не возникало и всё работало. При развороте на бегетовском сервере началась ошибка:

```
Class 'app\Models\Agency' not found
```

при вызове Agency::find()

И так для при работе со всеми контроллерами, расположенными в папке admin (admin/agency, к примеру).

Вот вставки из контроллера:

```
namespace app\controllers\admin;

use Yii;
use app\Models\Advertisement;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
```

PHPStorm на локалке не ругался. Как правильно организовать неймспейсы в этом случае?

Answer (score 0):

app\Models должен быть с маленькой буквы
Обратите внимание при генерации кода через Gii на этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ошибку, исходя из неполной информации в впоросе, то проблема у вас скорее всего в том, что автозагрузчик (скорее всего composer autoloader), не может найти нужный файл с этим классом.

Возможно у вас проблема с регистром названия файла. Делом в том, что в линуксе названия файлов регистрозависимые, а например на Mac OS нет. И код работающий на маке не будет работать при деплое на сервер.

Сверьте название этого класса и неймспейса с названием файла.